# "Security updates for current Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) ended on 2016-08-04”

Tags: 14.04, updates, update-manager, hardware-enablement-stack

Freshly installed 14.04.5 LTS trusty system, 4.2.0-42-generic, fully updated (using Synaptic). Now when I log on I get the title message. And:

"There is a graphics stack installed on this system. An upgrade to a configuration supported for the full lifetime of the LTS will become available on 2016-07-21 and can be installed by running 'update-manager' in the Dash."

Isn't Synaptic equivalent to or better than Update Manager? Anyway, update-manager repeats the hwe-support-status warning ("New important security and hardware support update"), proposes an "Install..." button (without stating *what* it'll update), then warns that "Requires installation of untrusted packages". Clicking "OK" apparently just dismisses update-manager (there is no "proceed anyway" option).

How can I get the darn system to update? It may be that there is a security key that needs to be imported, but which one?

Comment: Upgrade to Xenial HWE and you will get updates.

Comment: Nice try, Pilot6, but your comment is too curt: it does not identify the package that needs to be installed (a user needs a specific name because there are so many, and because none are called "hwe" in part or in whole).

The remaining issue is why the automatic update did not suggest the appropriate course of action.

Comment: That's why it is a comment, not an answer ;-) The GUI updater suggests to install a new HWE and has an "Install" button for that. You gave a good answer yourself.

Comment: Except that the install fails silently, leaving the user clueless as to how to fix the dang thing.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was buried in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL : I needed to upgrade to xserver-xorg-lts-xenial and dump the old kernel (4.2.0) in favour of the newer one (4.4.0) installed by that suite of packages.

Comment: xserver-xorg-lts-xenial seems to be missing a dependency: libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial. You'll need this to make the User Accounts control panel functional.

Answer (score 0):

According to Ubuntu official documentation at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

**Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Trusty Tahr**

The 14.04.2 and newer point releases will ship with an updated kernel and X stack by default. If you have installed with older media you can use the following to install the newer HWE kernel derived from 16.04 (Xenial):

**Desktop**

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
```

**Multiarch Desktop**

If you run a multiarch desktop (for example, i386 and amd64 on amd64, for gaming or Wine), you may find you need a slightly more involved command, like this:

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial:i386
```

**Server**

Install the HWE kernel derived from 16.04 (xenial):

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial
```